# DateTime method chaining problem

Tags: php

This works:

```
$aWeekAfterDate = new DateTime(); 
$aWeekAfterDate->modify('+1 week');
$aWeekAfterDate->format('d.m.Y');
```

But this:

```
$aWeekAfterDate = new DateTime(); 
$aWeekAfterDate->modify('+1 week')->format('d.m.Y');
```

Gives me this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function
>   format() on a non-object in ... on
>   line ...
>
> Fatal error (shutdown): Call to a
>   member function format() on a
>   non-object in ... on line ...

I have looked up the [DateTime::modify](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) method in the documentation and its return value is this:

> Returns the DateTime object for method
>   chaining or FALSE on failure.

Why is method chaining not working?

I am using PHP version 5.2.6.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Changelog**

```
Version   Description 
5.3.0     Changed the return value on success from NULL to DateTime.
```

So returning the DateTime object for chaining was only introduced in PHP 5.3.0

Comment: Easily overlooked, unless you've been stung by it before